# MySQL - Populate table column with values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, relational-database

Need some help please. Creating a basic relational database and trying to add column values from my account table to my login table. However, bit stuck on how to achieve this. I'm trying to take the AccountID, Username, Sign_in data to populate the Login table but nothing appear when executed.
my code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Account 
(  
  AccountID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Title VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,  
  FirstName varchar(16) NOT NULL,  
  LastName varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
  DOB DATE,  
  Email VARCHAR(255),  
  Username varchar(32) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  Sign_in varchar(32) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (AccountID)
);
ALTER TABLE Account AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Login 
(  
  LoginID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  AccountID INT NOT NULL,  
  Username varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
  Sign_in varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  LoginDate TIMESTAMP(6),
  FOREIGN KEY (AccountID) REFERENCES Account(AccountID),
  FOREIGN KEY (Username) REFERENCES Account(Username),
  FOREIGN KEY (Sign_in) REFERENCES Account(Sign_in)
);
ALTER TABLE Login AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
```

and tried the query (edited from a similar query found on this forum) to no avail

```
INSERT INTO Login
(
  AccountID,
  Username,
  Sign_in
)
SELECT
a.AccountID, a.Username, a.Sign_in
FROM Account a
INNER JOIN Login
ON a.AccountID = l.AccountID;
Select * from Login;
```

Help/advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the point of relational databases.  You simply want to map to the primary key *and then look up the other values*.  You don't want to store the values in two places.

So:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Account  (  
  AccountID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Title VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,  
  FirstName varchar(16) NOT NULL,  
  LastName varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
  DOB DATE,  
  Email VARCHAR(255),  
  Username varchar(32) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  Sign_in varchar(32) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Login  (  
  LoginID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  AccountID INT NOT NULL,  
  LoginDate TIMESTAMP(6),
  FOREIGN KEY (AccountID) REFERENCES Account(AccountID)
);
```

Then if you want the `username` or `sign_in`, you use a `JOIN` to look up that information.

I don't see a reason to set the auto-increment values.  There is generally no problem having them start at `1` in all tables.

Comment: I knew this was going to be pointed out, I have my reasons and it relates to another table which links various other tables. But I'd like to know how to insert the specified values from the Account to Login. The coding seems to execute fine but it doesn't produce the intended result as I get "There are no results to be displayed." As I said, the code appear to be fine, I'd like the values to be inserted and appear as intended. Thanks

Comment: @BeavertownPint . . . You can `JOIN` between these tables to `JOIN` to other tables as well.  You don't want to duplicate data across tables under most circumstances.

Comment: Sorry, me again! removed the `LoginID` and Referenced the `AccountID` as `PK` for the `Login` table. Then ran: `SELECT Account.AccountID, Account.Username, Account.Sign_in
FROM Account
INNER JOIN Login
ON Account.AccountID = Login.AccountID;` I still get no results to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work it out...

```
INSERT INTO Login (AccountID, Username, Sign_in)
SELECT AccountID, Username, Sign_in
FROM Account;
```

Did take on board the advice regarding the Primary Key ID suggestion though. Cheers